# Determine system parameters with c# program

Tags: c#

I want to determinate some system information using a c# program.
As it would be reported by the linux command line tool [uname](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_uname.htm)
And I want do the same thing on my c# code.

One alternative could be starting some external program (or `uname` itself, if available) and write the output to a file, which could then be read by the C# program.

But have some native c# form to do this? For linux

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You'll find all of this information (and more) within the [System.Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class.

Comment: You're writing a c# program for linux? I'm assuming you'd be using Mono framework, which should have most of System.Environment available. The point of Mono is to not have to write OS-specific code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you need user name you can use

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

which is part of `System.Security.Principal` namespace.  However for other system information you might look in `System.Environment` class.

Comment: Note that this requires elevated permissions, but all 3 methods (`Environment.UserName`, `SystemInformation.UserName`, and this) require full trust.